# How to perform click event on SVG element in Capybara

Tags: javascript, selenium, svg, capybara

Hi I am new to Capybara and selenium.I am using `gem 'capybara' and gem 'selenium-webdriver'`.I have a view where I have to click on an icon.The html of the view is

```
<svg class="assign-job icon icon-box-outgoing" ng-click="something">
   <use xlink:href="#icon-box-outgoing"></use>
</svg>
```

I want to perform click event onto this element.I have also tried using xpath but that didn't work.I have attached a screenshot please find that.[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CSS selector to click on the `svg` element:

```
find(:css, "svg.assign-job.icon-box-outgoing").click
```

or to click on the `use` element:

```
find(:css, "use[href='#icon-box-outgoing']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xpath** to identify the element.

```
//div[@class='jobActionsDisplayDeterminer']/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='use'][@xlink:href='#icon-box-outgoing']
```